# Composing data-structures/strings matching a CFG

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, grammar, context-free-grammar

The JSON syntax is an example of a [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) (Context free grammar).

Valid JSON strings are a sequence of tokens constrained to a CFG... or, the tokens can -equivalently- be thought of as a structure of nested values.

Valid JSON strings can be sequentially composed to produce a new valid JSON string - but this is not the only way existing strings can be combined.  If the first string were an array, the second string could be 'inserted' as a new value at any position in the array - and strings can be composed into an infinite number of distinct new strings with the addition only of arrays.  By carefully choosing where to insert one string into an array in another, a large number of other possibilities are revealed.

I'm interested to establish a taxonomy of the ways in which valid strings can be composed.  I'm interested in all the compositions of values. I accept that a composition may require introduction of new characters such as ',' - to insert a value into an array.

It strikes me that this is a sufficiently fundamental question that there is likely (at least one) standard answer.  Does anyone know what I should look up?

Comment: " taxonomy of the ways in which valid strings" is part of the CFG, no? 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/equanimity/3763158824/

Comment: There is a close relationship between the grammar and what I'm trying to establish.  If I have two strings that parse using the grammar, I'm interested in ways in which the structures of values these strings represent can be combined to make a new string that will necessarily parse.  This relates to trying to construct large structures matching the grammar in a piecemeal fashion.  The CFG contains all the necessary information - but does not (straightforwardly) enumerate all the different ways to combine two valid structures.

Comment: BTW - I think this is more of a 'programming' challenge than an issue with abstract grammars.  I'd love to see examples of systems that construct larger syntactically correct strings from smaller ones - without needing to re-parse the combined string.

Comment: With hindsight, I'm not sure this is a sensible question... :S  If anyone can suggest systems that combine parsed strings in flexible ways, I'd be interested to review them... but I'm no longer convinced that there's a "neat" solution to my problem.